# How does PasteBin work in the code highlighting area?

Tags: codehighlighter

I think it's awesome how PasteBin highlights different languages, how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses GeSHI

- http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

---

No, maybe not geshi itself, but something similar. Anyway, check out geshi.

Answer (score 1):

http://pastebin.com uses Geshi. You can google it.